# Convert DataFrame column to datetime.time objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column of hours and dates that I need to convert to the time of day only. I know of the method `pd.to_datetime` but I don't need the dates, only the hours and minutes. Also, the dataset is pretty large (90k+ rows) so if there is an efficient way to do this, it will be of great help.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('RAB_EXP1_7d_DFT.CSV')
print(df)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
print(df['Time'])

0       2024-02-07 12:20:21
1       2024-02-07 12:20:26
2       2024-02-07 12:20:31
3       2024-02-07 12:20:35
4       2024-02-07 12:20:40
                ...
89967   2024-02-12 17:17:35
89968   2024-02-12 17:17:40
89969   2024-02-12 17:17:45
89970   2024-02-12 17:17:50
89971   2024-02-12 17:17:55
```

Edit: After reading the discussion in the comments, here is some more context. The data I have is from a sensor that adds a row of data every 5 seconds. It was running for 7 days but what I need is to see at which times the readings were above 0. My plan is to convert the 'Time' column to only the time of day and then plot it using Matplotlib to see when the readings went up.

Comment: Can you provide examples of input and output and your attempt to solve problem?

Comment: sorry, i added the code and output i have

Comment: I do not have your huge dataset. I really want to know for the future your timings on the different approaches (with `timeit` module for instance).

Comment: If you plan to select/filter/etc. based on time, the datetime data type is what you're looking for (just ignore the date if not needed). 90k+ rows is not what I would consider "large"; and pd.to_datetime is pretty efficient if you have for example ISO8601 formatted input (in pandas v2, set `format="ISO8601"` then...). Come back to "what is more efficient?" once you actually experience problems due to slow code execution - avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time
```

This return the time component, but then you lose the day information, which in your case might be relevant, since your data stretches many days

First edit:

You can also store the date information by using this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Time'].dt.date
```

Comment: No need for 2 steps as `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time` can be used to convert straight from the strings brought into the DF from the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have strings and you do not want to convert to a resource-consuming datetime function, I propose you the following (a fast vectorized function) :

```
import pandas as pd

dates = [
    "2024-02-07 12:20:21",
    "2024-02-07 12:20:26",
    "2024-02-07 12:20:31",
    "2024-02-07 12:20:35",
    "2024-02-07 12:20:40"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['DateTime'])

df['Hour_only'] = df['DateTime'].str.extract(r'(\d{2}:\d{2})')

print(df)
```

Result of the strings-pattern recognition function :

```
              DateTime Hour_only
0  2024-02-07 12:20:21     12:20
1  2024-02-07 12:20:26     12:20
2  2024-02-07 12:20:31     12:20
3  2024-02-07 12:20:35     12:20
4  2024-02-07 12:20:40     12:20
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `dt.time` mentioned in the other answer, you can also use the datetime accessor `dt` to convert to whatever format you want from https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

```
>>> a["Time"]
0   2024-02-18 09:09:30.894398
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> a["Time"].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
0    09:09:30
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

Here `"%H:%M:%S"` is just a representation of hour, minute and second as zero-padded numbers.

Do notice that after this operation, the type of the column is no longer  `datetime64[ns]`, but `object`, if that is somehow relevant to later operations.

Comment: `strftime` is a viable approach for some cases. OP is using the `pd.to_datetime` to convert already from object to datetime, converting that back into object doesn't really make sense...

Comment: Maybe. What makes sense depends on OP's use case, of which we don't know anything. Though `dt.time`  is probably a better approach, sure.

Comment: Granted! The thing is I've seen and commented on another question by OP that they might need to convert to datetime from object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006297/plotting-a-dataset-with-90k-rows-using-matplotlib

Comment: thank you for your answers. I added a bit more context to the question